# When i trying to upload images in MongoDB database, I'm getting a multer error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I used Gridfs Storage to store the images and multer for uploading the image in the MongoDB atlas database.
My database is connected and I tried Postman for uploading the image. But that is showing an error in the multer which is showing unexpected field error in the console.

Here is the server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import cors from 'cors'
import multer from 'multer'
import GridsFsStorage from 'multer-gridfs-storage'
import Grid from 'gridfs-stream'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import path from 'path'
import Pusher from 'pusher'


Grid.mongo=mongoose.mongo

//app config

const app=express()
const port=process.env.PORT || 8000

//middlewares

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

//db config

const mongoURI='mongodb+srv://avishakcb:CiKas0n86a1A7Xsm@project350v1.kmy5r.mongodb.net/feeddb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

const conn=mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI,{
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
});

mongoose.connect(mongoURI,{
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})

mongoose.connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log('DB connected')
})

let gfs

conn.once('open',()=>{
    console.log('DB Connected')
    gfs=Grid(conn.db,mongoose.mongo)
    gfs.collection('images')
})

const storage=new GridsFsStorage({
    url:mongoURI,
    file:(req,file)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            const filename=`image-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`

            const fileInfo={
                filename:filename,
                bucketName:'images'
            };

            resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    }
});

const upload=multer({storage});



//api routes
app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.status(200).send('hello'))

app.post('/upload/image',upload.single('file'),(req,res)=>{
    res.status(201).send(req.file)
})


//listen 

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`port ${port} is running`))
```

And the error I'm getting in the console log.

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Busboy.emit (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)   
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HeaderParser._finish (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8) 
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)    
    at SBMH.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at SBMH._sbmh_feed (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:159:14)     
    at SBMH.push (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)   
    at Dicer._oninfo (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (E:\Complete_web_development\TechBook\Tech_community\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:127:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

is file function recive promise?

```js
file: (req, file) => {
  const filename = `image-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`

  return {
    filename: filename,
    bucketName: 'images'
  };
}
```

try to return it directly

Comment: nope that's not working. Its giving an error at wrappedFileFilter

Comment: according to multer doc, LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE means your field name not in requst body

Answer (score 0):

If you get this because of postman

POSTMAN:
just write "file" in keyfield and in value : select any image

AS YOU HAVE: USED 'file' here

```
upload.single()
```